# How many reports options to present to the user of an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, reports, choices

I have created a Mood tracking app for iPhone, and the user can keep track of the user's moods and (optionally) take pictures to associate with moods.

I've used a similar app for a few months and was dissatisfied with the ways that app sorted and filtered photos, and I'm trying to do better.

I'm interested in knowing - **how many "pre-built" reports would make the users happy, without leaving them overwhelmed?**

In my case, I have 1 query that is absolutely required - all photos by date. By itself, showing only one option does not look good, and I can implement additional queries.

A side question : **Do I need to repeat the word "photos" for each row of the table? Or is the "View Photos" header alone enough?**

[image: Choices]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How many reports options to present to the user of an iPhone app?**

The answer is simple: *provide enough* options to fulfill user's need. That leads to question: **What does a user want to achieve by viewing the pictures?** Is it:

a) See pictures relevant to her mood

b) See pictures that could change her mood

c) Something else actually?

The huge part of user experience is made of interaction. **There are too few details in your question** in order to be able to answer it precisely, **but you can already answer some questions**:

- Do you need the defaults for easy start or do you plan making such list static?
- Would the users use all the filters or would they have preferred, mostly used ones?
- Do a user care about what other users think? Would she like to see "popular", "hot" or "top rated" photos?

Other than that would be usability approach. User usually feels *"overwhelmed"* when a list is large **and** is not consistent with her thinking, mind model. When a list is large but it's conceptual model is useful and understandable then she feels uncomfortable at most. She may not even notice such discomfort if such a list is rarely used.